# Why this opcode doesn't work properly on ARM

Tags: assembly, arm

Writing the opcodes on ARM, I face an error.

```
8054:       e92d1fff        push    {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, sl, fp, ip}
```

The above is the result of disassembly by objdump; `\xe9\x2d\x1f\xff` is the same to `push {r0-r12}`.

But in another program, this opcode doesn't work properly like:

```
1e75:       e9              .byte   0xe9<BR>
1e76:       1f2d            .short  0x1f2d<BR>
1e78:       Address 0x06001e78 is out of bounds.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is this other program?

Comment: `1e75: e9`.. Why is your `push` instruction starting at an odd address? ARM instructions should be word aligned, and Thumb instructions half-word aligned. Also, unless you've happened to come upon a big-endian ARM CPU, the byte sequence should be `0xff,0x1f,0x2d,0xe9`.

Answer (score 0):

The disassembler is putting addresses and opcode values for your convenience; you should strip them when you want to assemble them back:

`push {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, sl, fp, ip}`

If that's not the issue, paste the *exact* text you're trying to assemble.